# Storing configurations as JSON file or in DB

Tags: json, database-design, web-applications, architecture

I am developing a small project management system using .NET core 5.0 with Angular as frontend.

While going through various levels I have got a situation to store configurations of each project. Other details with specific structure such as finance, timelines, milestones, objectives are all in dedicated tables. But the configurations needs to be little scalable. Thats why I thought about json .

But please suggest me the best solution among this.

One JSON file for all project files with along with ID of each project.

Next is separate configuration file for each project and the file path to be specified in DB in Project Master

Another option I thought is to store the JSON configuration of each project in DB table itself

```
{
   "Projects":[
      {
         "ID":37,
         "Name":"Project 1",
         "Sidebar":"Y",
         "Toolbar":"N",
         "Budget":{
            "Historical":"Y",
            "RestrictPrevUpdate":"Y"
         },
         "Board":{
            "FeatureEdit":"Y",
            "TaskAdd":"Y"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Above is a sample. In real case there are 50-60 configurations

Please suggest a best way to handle it.

Comment: Please add more details on what the `configurations` contain. Are they app-specific configs? Like number of threads, memory sizes, etc?

Comment: Its Project Specific. So every projects having separate configurations. Updated the questions

Answer (score 2):

Use the datatype `json` in an SQL database.

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    info json NOT NULL
);
```

See: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json for examples.